# How to convert UTC time to unix timestamp

Tags: go

I am looking for an option to convert UTC time string to unix timestamp.

The string variable I have is `02/28/2016 10:03:46 PM` and it needs to be converted to a unix timestamp like `1456693426`

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at the `time` package, it has everything you need.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of, the unix timestamp `1456693426` does not have the time `10:03:46 PM` but `9:03:46 PM` in UTC.

In the `time` package there is the function [Parse](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) with expects a layout to parse the time. The layout is constructed from the reference time `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006`. So in your case the layout would be `01/02/2006 3:04:05 PM`. After using [Parse](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) you get a `time.Time` struct on which you can call [Unix](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix) to receive the unix timestamp.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "01/02/2006 3:04:05 PM"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, "02/28/2016 9:03:46 PM")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t.Unix())
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danilo.Cheers.