# How to set and parse the time inside of a body request?

Tags: go, http-post, go-gin

I am using Go with Gin Gonic, and I have something like this:

```
import (
  "time"
)

type BodyType struct {
  YourDate: time.Time
}

func doThingWithPost(c *gin.Context) {
  var theBody BodyType
  c.BindJSON(&theBody)

  c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": theBody.YourDate})
}

func main() {
    r.POST("/", doThingWithPost)
}
```

My intention would be to make a request body like this one:

```
{
  YourDate: 1589887669644
}
```

And then the server automatically gets the Int I am giving, and parses that date into the date format time.Time, is there a clean way to do this? if I try to write my own function that receives a "YourDate" of type int64 and parses to time.Time would I be reinventing the wheel here?

Comment: If your goal is to output the Unix time of the time, why not just call `Unix()`?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/35688419/13860

Comment: @Flimzy some edition set made that title to happen... sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Flimzy this have another issue, if you do so the type verification in a request is delegated to my own parser... but if you send in the request an string instead of an int the language itself solves this verification of the type by itself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom type and use it `BodyTyte` struct.

```
type SpecialDate struct {
    time.Time
}

type BodyType struct {
    YourDate SpecialDate
}
```

And write `UnmarshalJSON` for `SpecialDate` to parse millisecond into `time.Time`

```
func (sd *SpecialDate) UnmarshalJSON(input []byte) error {
    millis, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(input), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tm := time.Unix(0, millis*int64(time.Millisecond))
    sd.Time = tm
    return nil
}
```